# Why do I have to add sleep() when I am trying to use threads?

Tags: ios, swift, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file with a thread. However, the XML is large and I am storing over 20,000 items into my array. I thought of using a thread to help the parser parse the XML file as the table data loads. However, it seems like using a thread doesn't work. I still have to insert two sleep() in order for it work a little bit.

How can I parse my XML file and load data into my tableview simultaneously?

```
let hr115XMLParser = HR115XMLParser()
let billXMLParser = BillXMLParser()

var viewBillItems: [BillModel] = []

private var billItems: [BillModel]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        self.hr115XMLParser.parseFeed(url: "https://www.gpo.gov/smap/bulkdata/BILLSTATUS/115hr/sitemap.xml")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.fetchData()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }        
}

private func fetchData()
{
    sleep(20)

    for index in 0..<self.hr115XMLParser.billItems.count {
        print()
        print("NEW ITEM \(index)")
        print()

        self.billXMLParser.parseFeed(url: self.hr115XMLParser.billItems[index])

        sleep(5)

        print(self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billtitle)
        print(self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billfullName)
        print(self.self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billURL)

        print()
        print("END ITEM")
        print()

        var newViewBillItem = BillModel()

        newViewBillItem.billtitle = self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billtitle
        newViewBillItem.billfullName = self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billfullName
        newViewBillItem.billURL = self.billXMLParser.billItemsArray[index].billURL

        self.viewBillItems.append(newViewBillItem)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, do not use `sleep`. That is very, very wrong. Surely your XML parser has some delegate methods you can implement that tell your when the parsing is complete.

Comment: What is HR115XMLParser?

Comment: @MartinR HR115XMLParser is an XML parser that parses for the links to additional XML files that will allow me to load information from a Congressional bill. Particularly, the <loc> tag.

Comment: Without knowing its API (delegate methods, callbacks?) we can only *guess* how to use that parser properly. Where does it come from? Is there some documentation on its usage?

Comment: @rmaddy It does. Am I supposed to use it here? Where should I use it?

Comment: @MartinR I watched Duc Tran's tutorial on how to do XML Parsing [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fP69LI5bZlg&t=807s). I modified it accordingly for my project.

Answer (score 0):

`parseFeed` is an async functions than goes to another thread. This means that `fetchData()` will be called before the `parseFeed` function has finished.

In order to avoid this, **maybe** (i'm don't know HR115XMLParser to say it for certain) it is possible to use a closure.

```
self.hr115XMLParser.parseFeed(url: "https://www.gpo.gov/smap/bulkdata/BILLSTATUS/115hr/sitemap.xml") {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.fetchData()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```